# How to maintain NSTimer when iPhone in deep sleep?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'm making a tweak which lock screen and using `NSTimer` to unlock screen on time like 5 minutes delay. But the powerd of system will get iPhone into deep sleep and stop `NSTimer`, so the tweak can't unlock screen on time. 
Anyone have idea to fix it?
 A lot Appreciate!

Comment: Where did you set `NSTimer` ? Inside an app ? What is the status of your app after locking the phone (killed, active, on background)?

Answer (score 0):

The system uses an idle timer to determine when to put the device to sleep, in you app you can disable this by setting

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

This will stop the system from putting the phone to sleep while your app is running.